# Iphone,Realm browser error

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, realm

i'm new to realm database with xcode 8.i have configured realm framework in my application.Have downloaded realm browser with version of 2.1.2.Got browser path using code    `print(Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration.fileURL!`
When i enter the path in realm browser i'm getting following error

my url `Users/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/8E79997F-DBBE-4462-B8BA-4B8E680BBA91/data/Containers/Data/Application/BA3E606F-6D92-46F1-955F-733DA810370B/Documents/default.realm`

```
import UIKit
import RealmSwift

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let realm = try! Realm()

        try! realm.write {

            print(Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration.fileURL!)

           // realm.add(realmobject(Name:"test1",Address:"yyyy1",CNO:"9875642311"))


        }

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

[image: error while opening realm browser]o

Comment: Please provide some more context. Are you trying to display the contents of a local Realm file or a Realm Object Server? What is the URL (change any private parts to dummy data if needed)?

Comment: your url is invalid , check or show some related code

Comment: see this for e.g https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/4254

Comment: How are you opening the file in Realm Browser? Since you appear to be opening a local, non-synced Realm, you should be using File -> Open…, and then navigating to the file in question to open it. Since the path to the file is quite complex, you can use Cmd-Shift-G when the Open dialog is showing and paste the path to your Realm file to simplify navigating to it.